# Is there a way to force all Ruby(MRI) finalizers to run synchronously?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

I'm trying to unit test some logic around finalizer code, but in order
to do so, I need to know when all finalizers that *can* run *have* run.
That way, I can tell if the effects of the finalizers that should have
been realized, are in fact realized.

Thus far I've had no luck (on MRI 2.2), and the finalizers always seem
to run "later"

To be clear, I have no interest in forcing GC and finalizers to run
anywhere else except in the unit tests, but the finalization logic is
nuanced, and so I'm really not comfortable leaving it untested.

V8 provides a method just for this purpose, and it is really handy,
https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/include/v8.h#L5667 but I haven't
been able to find anything equally reliable in Ruby.

So my question is, how can I force a complete and synchronous run of all
GC, and all finalizers? Could this be done with a C extension even if
there's no public API do it with?

Here is a link to a script demonstrating the problem

https://gist.github.com/cowboyd/6caf13104a26210ec525

Comment: have you tried triggering GC several times?

Answer (score 2):

Googling, someone asked this same question in 2003 (!), and Matz himself responded saying basically no:

http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/87753

```
In message "How to unit test finalizers?"
    on 03/12/11, Samuel Tesla <samuel / thoughtlocker.net> writes:

|> Nothing.  There's no way to "ensure" instance to be GC'ed except for
|> program termination.  That's a weak (or charm) point of Ruby's GC.
|
|That's fine.  I'm guessing that the GC will eventually, most likely,
|collect those references.  The question then becomes, how can I
|reliably unit test my finalizer code if I can't reliably get it to
|execute?

How about not relying on finalizers, i.e. separate finalizing process
into a method, then call the method explicitly in the test?  You don't
have to test whether finalizers are called.  That's my responsibility.

              matz.
```

Comment: What about writing a C extension that could do it?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure, I have never written a C extension I must admit. But I'm not optimistic. Adding functionality with a C extension is one thing, but you're talking about somehow hooking into existing ruby code to... change the way GC works? Which is also pretty complicated stuff, easy to mess up (or ruin the performance characteristics of). And you'd possibly have to rewrite it with subsequent MRI release as the GC algorithms change. Or I could be totally wrong, not my area of expertise, but I'm not optimistic. Maybe someone else will answer.

Comment: Keep in mind, this would only be for testing. The extension would not be loaded except inside the test suite. The reason I want to explore all options is that the system under test itself is a C extension, and the ruby finalizer call out to C which then calls back into the extension. I'd like to test this round trip.

Comment: You can test the round-trip using the technique matz suggests, test the logic in methods apart from the finalizer (that the finalizer calls); but it doesn't test that your finalizers _really_ get called at all, matz suggests you just have to trust MRI on that. It also doesn't allow you to test, though, that your finalizer doesn't accidentally prevent GC at all, which can be a real problem, and I don't know how to test it either.  But sorry, I have no idea if you can do that, good luck, hope someone else answers!